# clang 18 gives error "non C++20 importable modules" for "import std"

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

the following code

```
import std;
int main(){}
```

compiled with clang 18:

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -fbuiltin-module-map
```

gives the error:

```
import of module 'std' imported non C++20 importable modules
```

while it works on clang 17.

anybody have an idea why?

Comment: https://libcxx.llvm.org/Modules.html states `Modules are an experimental feature. It has additional build requirements and not all libc++ configurations are supported yet. The work is still in an early development state and not considered stable nor complete.` I'd guess it simply wasn't enabled when libc++ was built

Comment: @HolyBlackCat its not a bug, its an incomplete/not enabled feature

Comment: It might also be that `import std` is a c++23 feature and you're trying to use it in c++20?

Comment: @AlanBirtles your comments make sense. But isn't it strange that it works on clang 17 but not 18 (as least according to the OP, I haven't tried) ?

Comment: @wohlstad probably just a bug in 17 not disabling the module for c++20

Comment: @AlanBirtles that can indeed explain it.